# Marketing Cloud - change subscribers from Held to Active

Tags: marketing-cloud, update, subscriber

I have a large list of subscribers I want to change from Held to Active.  I've tried the following

For multiple records:

Allsubscriber >> search >> criteria is subscriber status -undelivered > then export it. next change held status in export file as active >> then import in all subscriber with add and update or update.

But when I use this method, Marketing Cloud prompts me to approve each update individually.  So if you are updating 100 contacts, you have to click 100 times.  Is there no method that is a bulk update?  I am looking for a way to edit without writing code.  thanks MJ

Comment: The first question I would ask is why you think held subscribers are now valid and should be sent to. Sending to address that will simply bounce again and would hurt your reputation

Comment: We had not been using MC for very long, and don't send a large volume of e-mail on a consistent basis.  So some ISP blocked messages as they didn't "know" us.  I asked MC support to contact ISP on our behalf so they would not block.  It's true some of these may bounce again due to other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Automation Studio

Note:
This is not considering the point raised by @EazyE above. That is a valid point and I am guessing you will sort that separately.

- Step 1: SQL Activity to filter the required results into a DE. Make sure you have Subscriber Key (Or Subscriber ID) and Status
- Step 2: Data Extract Activity
- Step 3: File Transfer Activity to export to Enhanced FTP. In this, you should export the file to the Import Folder. (You can create a File Location in Setup pointing to the Import Folder. It will be then available in your drop down of the File Transfer Activity.)
- Step 4: Import the same exported file in Step 3. Choose All Subscriber List in the destination. Choose Action as Update